# Mac Chrome virus that inverts colours?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I dunno if this is a virus or not (if it is it doesn't seem to be doing much), but when I open Chrome, for HTML elements with the input tag, I've been getting messed up colours. It's not a biggie, but I wanted to check it's not a virus and see if anyone has had the same symptoms before?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's almost certainly not a virus; it looks like a development tool highlight—try disabling extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come across bugs like these that ended up being intended or unintended side effects of Chrome extensions or flags. Try disabling these first to make sure it's not one of these.

- To disable extensions:

  1. Go to `chrome://extensions/`.
  2. Uncheck `Enabled` for each enabled extension.
  3. Reload the buggy pages.
- To disable flags (developer options):

  1. Go to `chrome://flags/`.
  2. Click `Reset all to default` on the right.
  3. Click `Relaunch now` at the bottom of the page.

Disable these one by one until the problem goes away, so that you can not only fix the problem bug but also figure out what caused it in the first place.

Comment: Absolutely right! Somehow an extension that does EXACTLY THAT (pastelize colours or whatever they called it) installed itself in the browser! Thanks for the tip ;) No more head splitting colours :D